# unchecked radio button without using clear Check function of radio group, because radio group clear-check goes in loop

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

Could you please identify what i have done wrong in my code , as i am newbie to android and help ill be appreciated, please let me know if you required more info.

Actually i am working on dynamic Radio group creation and though on view pager using fragments like tabular/swiping layouts

What all i have tried for clearing radio Group/ radio Button

i have tried `radioGroup.clearCheck();` but in this case i have faced a looping issue so i just skipped this and thought to unchecked all buttons of my current radio group which is in listener but while doing this i am facing very unpredictive behavior, like some time i am not able to check another boton or can check two buttons

**Note what i am trying** : just i have changed something, what i want that, there are set of buttons i n radio group, and while i clicked on one button it is checked , but i clicked on another button of same radio group then previously checked button is not getting unchecked and even new buttons gets checked, so what i have done is that while is checked is call and code comes to my listener there i am checking if button is already checked then io am trying to unchecked same   , so is there any docs or something by which i can learn to create big amount of radio group dynamically and handle those. i believe that because i am creating buttons dynamically i am facing this issue

```
  private void checkOnClickedRadioGroupCalled(ArrayList<LinearLayout> setRadioGroupValuesLinearLayoutList) {
    for (final LinearLayout linearLayoutGroup : setRadioGroupValuesLinearLayoutList) {
        String linearLayoutTag = linearLayoutGroup.getTag() + Constant._RADIOGROUP;
        System.out.println("Radio group tag name : - " + linearLayoutTag);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewWithTag(linearLayoutTag);
        if (radioGroup == null) {
            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) getRadioInitialize(linearLayoutTag);
        }
        if (radioGroup != null) {

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    listOfRadioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
                    DynamicFieldUpdate.getButtonsCountAndInit(group,listOfRadioButtons);
                    RadioButton radioButtonInSideClickListner = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                    /*RadioButton mButton = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(0);
                    RadioButton mButton1 = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(1);*/
                        if(radioButtonInSideClickListner!=null && radioButtonInSideClickListner.isChecked()) {
                            /*mButton.setChecked(false);
                            mButton1.setChecked(false);*/
                            for(int i = 0;i<listOfRadioButtons.size();i++){
                            if(radioButtonInSideClickListner.getId() == getViewId(listOfRadioButtons.get(i))) {
                                radioButtonInSideClickListner.setText(listOfRadioButtons.get(i).getText());
                                radioButtonInSideClickListner.setChecked(true);
                            } else{
                                radioButtonInSideClickListner.setText(radioButtonInSideClickListner.getText());
                                radioButtonInSideClickListner.setChecked(false);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    addRadioGroupValuesViewListInputValue.add(group);

                }

                });

        }
    }

}
```

here is my code for creating radio group

```
    public static void setCustomRadioGroup(LinearLayout layout, Context context, ArrayList<String> setName, ArrayList<View> viewList) {
        int sizeOfList = setName.size();
        final RadioButton[] radioButtons = new RadioButton[setName.size()];
        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
        System.out.println(layout.getTag()+"_RadioGroup"+"   this is tag from dynamic layout creation");
        //set this in constant afterweard while dry run
        radioGroup.setTag(layout.getTag()+"_RadioGroup");
//      /*  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
//        );
//        layout.addView(radioGroup, params);*/

        //radioGroup.setTag();//create the RadioGroup
        if (setName.size() < 3) {
            radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        } else {
            radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        }
        //or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
        for (int i = 0; i < setName.size(); i++) {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(context);
            radioButtons[i].setText(setName.get(i));
            String id = layout.getTag()+setName.get(i);
            radioButtons[i].setId(id.hashCode());
            Log.v("Selected", "New radio item id in Dynamic fiels: " + id.hashCode());

            radioGroup.addView(radioButtons[i]);
        }
        layout.addView(radioGroup);
        viewList.add(radioGroup);

    }
```

Comment: It's not quite clear where your code is at, as far as you trying to fix the issue, but as long as you don't call `setChecked()` on any `RadioButton`s inside the `RadioGroup`'s `OnCheckedChangeListener`, `clearCheck()` should work.

Comment: hi mike do you need more info?on this

Comment: Not necessarily. As I mentioned, `clearCheck()` should work just fine, as long as you don't call `setChecked()` on any of the `RadioButton`s inside `onCheckedChanged()`. I was just uncertain as to what you're doing inside that method currently, as far as whether those `setChecked()` calls are an attempt at the fix.

Comment: hi mike i just have updated my question with some note could you please help , now this issue banging my head. as i am trying to create some new app with totally dynamic behavior, i am totally new to android and backed i can handle easily.

Comment: i even tried removing listener ,and faced same behavior

Comment: Then it sounds like the code that creates the groups is wrong.

Comment: i just have added radio group creation code in question, is there anything you see i have done in wrong way

Comment: please help help will be appreciated, you around?

Comment: Remove the `radioButtons[i].setId(id.hashCode());` line, and test again.

Comment: omg!! that was horrible, Thanks buddy its working now , where exactly issue was ,is it like setting id to radio button ? but why

Comment: `hashCode()` can return negative values, which aren't valid `View` IDs, so the `RadioGroup` couldn't find and keep track of the `RadioButton`s correctly. If you add a `RadioButton` without an ID to a `RadioGroup`, it will take care of generating a valid ID for it, so you don't really need to set one on each `RadioButton` yourself. If you do, just make sure it's positive, and unique within the `RadioGroup`.

Comment: thanks, That was something new for me , really appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, it took me a minute to see it myself. Kinda tricky. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: what if i am using like this Math.abs(setHint.trim().hashCode()) this is not for radio button for some othere fields

Comment: Well, it would be a valid ID, but there's a possibility that it might not be unique within its hierarchy. That won't cause a crash or anything, but `findViewById()` will only ever return the first `View` it finds with a given ID. Unless you have a huge number of `View`s you're doing that for, the chances are slim that two will get the same ID, but it is a possibility.

Comment: ok , thanks for this .